# In Rails, using Figaro, Zeus and RSpec, how to set the secret token from Figaro when running specs?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, zeus

**TL;DR:** My Figaro variables are not set when I run `zeus rspec spec/`.

---

The title pretty much explains the problem briefly, but I'll elaborate.

In a Rails 4 application, I'm using [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to store environment specific configuration, e.g. the Rails secret token (`Rails.configuration.secret_key_base`). This works fine in itself. I am also using [Zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) to preload my Rails configuration, which also works like a charm.

However, when combined and running my RSpec specs (through `zeus rspec spec/`) my Rails secret token is removed. This, of course, outputs a deprecation warning and then errors out:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base.

[...]

RuntimeError:
  You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.
```

While the specs are running, I notice that the Rails environment has changed (`Rails.env == "test"`), and I presume this might be done by Zeus automagically, as it happens even if I remove my changing the environment from my *spec_helper.rb* file.

It might also be worth mentioning that my specs run completely fine without Zeus.

I found that if I explicitly set the secret token to a value in *spec_helper.rb*, then stuff works fine from within Zeus, but my Figaro environment variables are not present.

Basically, it seems as if my environment variables from Figaro are not being set when Zeus runs the specs. If anyone knows how I could make Zeus set these upon running my tests, that would be super awesome!

Much appreciated, people. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just switched to using the `dotenv` gem:

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Add the following line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'dotenv', groups: [:development, :test]
```

`bundle install`, and restart Zeus - you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @han. I have moved to Spring for my application preloading and that seems to set the environment correctly. That means this is not really an issue for me anymore. :-)